# (SOLVED) Unity Crashing After Installing the "2D Tilemap Extras" package

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

So, I am not really sure why, but when I open this exact project and install either the "2D Tilemap Extras" package alone or the "2D" package, that includes the "2D Tilemap Extras" package, the engine crashes, and chrashes every time its opened. Only fix I found is to remove the package from the "manifest.json" file from the "Packages" folder and delete the "packages-lock.json" file, and enter the Safe Mode. But even after that, I can't do anything because I am stuck in Safe mode, because the Engine cannot run without the "2D" mod.

I am not really sure what is causing the problem, because I can open other projects with the package without any problem. I tried to find help on the internet, but I found nothing. I only use my own scripts and packages from the Package Manager. This bug first happened today after I tried to use the Version Control, and I have worked on the project without any problems even after the last "2D Tilemap Extras" package update.

UPDATE: It is also happening with the "Unity UI" package

Comment: I'd probably consider a clean install; make a copy of your Assets, Library, ProjectSettings and UserSettings folders into a different directory, then create a new project from those (Unity Hub > 'Add' button > 'Add project from disk'). Open in safe mode as you'll get errors about missing packages and re-add the packages using the Package Manger.

Comment: I discovered that something in the ProjectSettings folder was corrupted. Now I am fixing the project settings! Also Thank You @Absinthe for the advice!